# ReactNative NativeBase android Fab childs not show ever

Tags: android, react-native, floating-action-button, native-base

Fab main button show on screen but fab childs not show ever

VSCode auto implement not offer FAB props like 'direction' , 'active' or ... !!!

My example snippet code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { NativeBaseProvider, Text, Fab, Icon, Container, Header, View, Button } from "native-base";

const ScreenTEST = ({ navigation }) => {
   const [fabActive, setFabActive] = useState(false)
   return (
      <NativeBaseProvider>
         <Container>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
               <Fab
                  active={fabActive}
                  variant={'solid'}
                  direction='up'
                  placement={'bottom-left'}
                  bg={'blue.500'}
                  containerStyle={{}}
                  onPress={() => { console.log('FAB'); setFabActive(!fabActive) }}
               >
                  <Icon name="share" size={50} />
                  <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
                     <Icon name="logo-whatsapp" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }}>
                     <Icon name="logo-facebook" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
                     <Icon name="mail" />
                  </Button>
               </Fab>
            </View>
         </Container>
      </NativeBaseProvider>
   )
}
export { ScreenTEST }
```

Output :

[image]

**>>> after click on it , LOG : 'FAB' in console but nothing happens on screen**

Comment: Which version of `native-base` library you are using? This component may not support child component.

Comment: This version : native-base": "^3.4.25", "react-native": "0.71.1" @kiuQ

Comment: You can check fab component source code in `native-base` [(here)](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/components/composites/Fab/Fab.tsx). The floating button contains one child: `label`. You may try to insert your custom component in `label` props. If it doesn't work, you may need to find another library.

Answer (score 0):

*Hello,* 
I'm also not sure exactly why the FAB in NativeBase is no longer functioning properly. 
I do remember it worked quite well before, so I tried using it myself, ***but kept encountering failures.*** (Clicking FAB, nothing happenend. ;l ) 
As a result, **I ended up creating my own.**
Below is the code I came up with. I hope it helps.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
...


const [fabActive, setFabActive] = useState(false);


const handleFabPress = () => {
        setFabActive(!fabActive);
      };

...

   <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleFabPress}
      style={{backgroundColor: "#whateveryouwant", width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", position: "absolute", bottom: 70, right: 30}}>
     <Ionicons    size={28} name="add" style={{ color: "#FFF"}} />
   {/* FAB Children -- Buttons */}
  {fabActive && 
            <View style={{position: "absolute", bottom: 130, right: 30,}}>
                  <Button>
                <Icon as={Ionicons} name="menu" size="sm" color="white" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button>
                <Icon as={Ionicons} name="search" size="sm" color="white" />
                  </Button>
                  <Button>
              <Icon as={Ionicons} name="settings" size="sm" color="white" />
                  </Button>
                </View>
                   }

   </TouchableOpacity>
```